# Turn off Tabulous css scaffolding in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I just installed [tabulous](https://github.com/techiferous/tabulous/blob/master/REFERENCE.md) gem in my rails app. I have installed twitter bootstrap aswell (using [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)).

I'm having issues turning off the css scaffolding of tabulous. I can't "turn it off" as recomended, and it overrides my bootstrap css.

Reading tabulous references, i assume that by default there is no css scaffolding, and to turn it on you should add the `use_css_scaffolding` line to the `tabulous.rb` file.

I tried (in spite not being anywhere in documentation) using `use_css_scaffolding = false` with no results. Css is still appearing in my resulting html.

My `tabulous.rb` configuration file looks like this:

```
Tabulous.setup do

  tabs do

    ...

  end

  customize do

   renderer :bootstrap_pill

 end

  # The following will insert some CSS straight into your HTML so that you
  # can quickly prototype an app with halfway-decent looking tabs.
  #
  # This scaffolding should be turned off and replaced by your own custom
  # CSS before using tabulous in production.

end
```

Where else can i look to disable this css scaffolding?

Answer (score 0):

With a simple rails server restart i could solve the problem.